# Как убрать ненужные слова и оставить только цифры

Tags: python, csv

Я новичок в программировании. Имеется csv файл, в нем 377185 строк. Все значения в столбце baths - str, подскажите как убрать из почти каждой строки данного столбца слово baths? В ручную 377тыс. обрабатывать нереально. Сначала хотел попробовать регулярные выражения, но для их использования нужно, чтобы цифры были в формате int либо float, для применения поиска, я правильно понимаю?

```
id baths
0   3.5 
1   3 Baths
2   2 Baths
5   8 
200 2
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) - он идеально подходит для обработки, анализа и визуализации табличных данных:

```
import pandas as pd  # https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

# парсим CSV файл в Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",")

#  в столбце `baths` удаляем все символы, кроме цифр и точки
df["baths"] = df["baths"].str.replace(r"[^\d\.]", "", regex=True)

# записываем DataFrame обратно в CSV файл
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

---

Регулярное выражение `r"[^\d\.]"` - обозначает:

1. все что в в квадратных скобках - любой символ из набора
2. если **первым** символом внутри квадратных скобок является `^` - значит применить отрицание к набору символов. Т.е. по смыслу - любые символы, кроме указанных в квадратных скобках, после `^`.
3. `\d` - обозначает любую цифру от `0` до `9`.
4. `\.` - обозначает символ точки, т.к. `.` без экранирования обозначает на языке RegEx - любой одиночный символ.

Все вместе это обозначает - найти все символы кроме цифр и символа точки и заменить их на пустую строку, т.е. удалить.

PS существуют сервисы, которые позволяют протестировать `RegEx` и объяснить (на английском) как он работает. Например - [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3MJlZ8/1)

[Документация по встроенному модулю `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Проверил. Работает.

Comment: @A_Vaclav, спасибо за проверку )

Comment: Просьба: добавьте к своему ответу расшифровку шаблона r"[^\d\.]" и ссылочку где подробнее об этом можно почитать... если не трудно. Для "полноты" знаний так сказать... )

Comment: @A_Vaclav, добавил пояснения в ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. )

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
with open("d:\\data.csv") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [line.lower().replace("baths", "") for line in lines]

with open("d:\\data.csv", 'w') as file:
    file.write(''.join(lines))
```

тут сначала перевожу строку в нижний регистр, чтобы удалить все `baths` в независимости от регистра

недостаток - всё будет переведено в нижний регистр, если этого не надо, то алгоритм можно усложнить:

```
with open("d:\\data.csv") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = [(' '.join(word for word in line[:-1].split() + '\n') if word.lower() != 'baths') for line in lines]

with open("d:\\data.csv", 'w') as file:
    file.write(''.join(lines))
```

тут что бы все работало корректно приходится отрезать у строки последний символ (который является переводом на новую строку), а затем добавлять его заново при сборке строки из слов с исключенным `baths`

Comment: `lines = [line.lower().replace("baths", "") for line in lines]` -зОчем lower()?
`lines = [line.replace("Baths", "") for line in lines]`

Comment: да и пробел в начало добавить... что бы уж "все ровно"...

Comment: ну просто автор пишет о замене `baths`, а в примере `Baths`, вот и подумалось - вдруг там и так и так может быть

Comment: формат csv... вы же имя столбца грохнули, уважаемый @Zhihar.

Comment: и что? человеку не хочется 200 тысяч строк руками править, а 1 строку уж можно и восстановить вручную. Если совсем невмоготу, то можно `lines = lines[0] + [.... in lines[1:]]` сделать